# Matrix Proof- Show that P is idempotent

Tags: matrices, idempotents

Show that P is idempotent. I'm very confused on how to prove it. I get stuck on the first step 
P=(X(X^TX)^-1X^T

It then asks to obtain Eigen values of P given Matrix x.
The rows for the matrix is as follows
row 1: 1 2 , row 2: 1 4, row 3: 1 1, row 4: 1 3

Comment: $P$ is idempotent whenever $P^2 = P \cdot P = P$. Have you tried calculating $P^2$?

Comment: You are getting stuck with matrix multiplication?